# convert sql query to critera query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate-criteria

Can some one help me convert this to criteria query . I am using Hibernate and when i used this in native query, it returned me an empty result set :(

```
 select * from Experiment e,launchman l,launchman_has_servergroups        ls,servergroup s 
where e.IDEXPERIMENT = l.EXPERIMENT_IDEXPERIMENT 
and l.idLaunchman = ls.LAUNCHMAN_IDLAUNCHMAN 
and ls.SERVERGROUP_IDSERVERGROUP=s.idservergroup 
and s.servergroupname = 'uatServers';
```

Comment: If this didn't work in "native query" mode, doesn't that mean that the SQL query itself is not working?

Comment: yes its supposed to be. when i checked  in DB there is data .

Comment: If at all i have to convert how would that look like ?